# Facing ISsue while pulling images in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I was trying to create Image via DockerFile.

While pulling image I am facing below error

```
Pulling repository docker.io/library/ubuntu
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images: dial tcp 52.45.107.172:443: getsockopt: network is unreachable
```

Could anyone help me out ,were exactly the issue.Its proxy issue, however I set the proxy Still its not working

Comment: Can you pull any other docker images?
What happens if you ```curl -v https://index.docker.io``` ?

Comment: Where did you set your proxy and how are you running the docker daemon? Is this Mac/Win?

Comment: CONNECT index.docker.io:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: index.docker.io:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  
This is the output if I do " curl -v https://index.docker.io"